# Login not working with camunda-bpm-identity-keycloak plugin

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, camunda-plugin

I try to implement the camunda-bpm-identity-keycloak plugin into camunda. I followed the following description: https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-bpm-identity-keycloak/tree/master/examples/sso-kubernetes

When I enter the url I want to login (for example: http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/cockpit/default/#/dashboard), I am redirected to the keycloak login masks and there I enter username and password. So far so good.

Then the computer is working a few seconds and the login mask of camunda is shown instead that I am logged in into Camunda. -> When I try to enter username and password there, directly into the camunda login mask it is not working.

When I check the network traffic -> It seems that the authentication is working fine, but the authorization not. -> in the default request header to: http://localhost:8080/camunda/api/admin/auth/user/default there is a status: 404 and the log in from Eclipse we see on 11:15:52.386 that there is a first error.

The idea is of course that after I entered the login credentials on the keyloak mask, I am directly logged in in Camunda. Do you know what I should do that this is working? Why happens this errors and what can we do to solve it?  Thanks for your help.

Kind regards

```
    2021-11-16 11:15:51.556 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-11-16 11:15:51.603 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /camunda/api/cockpit/plugin/cockpitPlugins/static/app/plugin.css.map
2021-11-16 11:15:51.603 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:51.603 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:51.605 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /camunda/api/cockpit/plugin/cockpitPlugins/static/app/plugin.css.map] with attributes [authenticated]
2021-11-16 11:15:51.605 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /camunda/api/cockpit/plugin/cockpitPlugins/static/app/plugin.css.map
2021-11-16 11:15:51.605  INFO 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.c.bpm.zahlungsauftrag.CorsFilter       : Adding CORS Headers ...............
2021-11-16 11:15:51.612 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-11-16 11:15:51.767 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /camunda/app/cockpit/locales/en.json?_=1637057751654
2021-11-16 11:15:51.768 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:51.769 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:51.770 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /camunda/app/cockpit/locales/en.json?_=1637057751654] with attributes [authenticated]
2021-11-16 11:15:51.770 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /camunda/app/cockpit/locales/en.json?_=1637057751654
2021-11-16 11:15:51.770  INFO 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.c.bpm.zahlungsauftrag.CorsFilter       : Adding CORS Headers ...............
2021-11-16 11:15:51.782 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-11-16 11:15:52.058 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /camunda/app/cockpit/fonts/IBMPlexSans-Italic.otf
2021-11-16 11:15:52.062 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.062 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.063 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /camunda/app/cockpit/fonts/IBMPlexSans-Italic.otf] with attributes [authenticated]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.063 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /camunda/app/cockpit/fonts/IBMPlexSans-Italic.otf
2021-11-16 11:15:52.063  INFO 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.c.bpm.zahlungsauftrag.CorsFilter       : Adding CORS Headers ...............
2021-11-16 11:15:52.070 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-11-16 11:15:52.073 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /camunda/app/cockpit/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
2021-11-16 11:15:52.073 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.143 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.144 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /camunda/app/cockpit/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2] with attributes [authenticated]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.144 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /camunda/app/cockpit/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
2021-11-16 11:15:52.144  INFO 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.c.bpm.zahlungsauftrag.CorsFilter       : Adding CORS Headers ...............
2021-11-16 11:15:52.148 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-11-16 11:15:52.364 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /camunda/api/admin/auth/user/default
2021-11-16 11:15:52.364 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.365 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.366 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /camunda/api/admin/auth/user/default] with attributes [authenticated]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.367 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /camunda/api/admin/auth/user/default
2021-11-16 11:15:52.367  INFO 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.c.bpm.zahlungsauftrag.CorsFilter       : Adding CORS Headers ...............
2021-11-16 11:15:52.383 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-11-16 11:15:52.386 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2021-11-16 11:15:52.387 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.392 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /camunda/api/engine/engine/
2021-11-16 11:15:52.410 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.411 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2021-11-16 11:15:52.411 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.412 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.414 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /camunda/api/engine/engine/] with attributes [authenticated]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.415 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /camunda/api/engine/engine/
2021-11-16 11:15:52.417  INFO 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.c.bpm.zahlungsauftrag.CorsFilter       : Adding CORS Headers ...............
2021-11-16 11:15:52.498 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-11-16 11:15:52.506 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-11-16 11:15:52.572 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /camunda-welcome
2021-11-16 11:15:52.573 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.573 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.574 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /camunda-welcome] with attributes [authenticated]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.574 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /camunda-welcome
2021-11-16 11:15:52.574  INFO 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.c.bpm.zahlungsauftrag.CorsFilter       : Adding CORS Headers ...............
2021-11-16 11:15:52.580 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-11-16 11:15:52.581 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2021-11-16 11:15:52.581 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.582 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [demo], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=TQRTuOB7jfEpJhkprw9C8w, sub=42b00419-100d-45d4-a5ff-3e4a8d10189a, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myRealm, typ=ID, preferred_username=demo, given_name=Roger, nonce=izuML55M8n-7DPDsIQot1Ttdlb2l5C1ajrHlI0QiRXc, sid=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, aud=[camunda-identity-service], acr=1, azp=camunda-identity-service, auth_time=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, name=Roger Tester, exp=2021-11-16T10:20:48Z, session_state=9a44262b-d8fd-46ac-8f52-ade8867f2191, family_name=Tester, iat=2021-11-16T10:15:48Z, email=demo.demo@akb.ch, jti=dcb0306d-9189-4a53-b929-83270468ebb1, username=demo}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=C920A462E840F9CC4E6D6957D16385C2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_camunda-rest-api, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2021-11-16 11:15:52.582 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2021-11-16 11:15:52.586 DEBUG 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```